# Why MySQL returning error when executing query to get count of per month?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the count of monthly added records, I made a query which is returning following error

> '#1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column
>   'db_records.ws_newsfeed.date_added'; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Below is query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_by_month, MONTH(`date_added`) AS month_number,
MONTHNAME(`date_added`) AS month_name 
FROM `ws_newsfeed` 
WHERE MONTH(`date_added`) = 1 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

I have searched it and also found some related threads, but still unable to resolve this. Can anyone guide me where is the issue that i fix it. I would like to appreciate if someone guide me. Thank You

Comment: Why do you use `MONTH(date_added) = 1`?  you need  just January months count?

Comment: @OtoShavadze No actually this query is for all months, so that number can be in 1 to 12

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_by_month FROM `ws_newsfeed` WHERE MONTH(`date_added`) = 1;
```

SELECT  MONTH(`date_added`) AS month_number, MONTHNAME(`date_added`) AS month_name FROM `ws_newsfeed` WHERE MONTH(`date_added`) = 1;

Comment: It does not returning the count

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

(Note, that this query doesn't shows years, shows only months).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_by_month, MONTH(`date_added`) AS month_number, MONTHNAME(`date_added`) as MONTH_NAME FROM `ws_newsfeed` 
GROUP BY date_added
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by month_number:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_by_month, MONTH(`date_added`) AS month_number, MONTHNAME(`date_added`) AS month_name FROM `ws_newsfeed` WHERE MONTH(`date_added`) = 1 GROUP BY month_number
```

The rule of thumb is that if you're not aggregating a column, you need to be grouping by it.